# ftp_login issue with "at" and "dollar" character on password

Tags: php, ftp, special-characters

I've a php issue probably depending on "special chars" on FTP password assigned me.

The issue is that PHP script (that's connecting from a linux to a Windows NT FTP server)

```
 <?
 ftp_connect('host.mydomain.com');
 ftp_login('stefano', 'F91$@xyz456');    #-- Single quote used
 ?>
```

gets me such error

```
 PHP Warning:  ftp_login(): User stefano cannot log in
```

I think that's depending on the password assigned me as I'm else able to connect to same host (and with same credentials) from ftp command line or GUI (like FileZilla).
Has anyone had the same issue?
On top of that I've already tried to escape both \' and \@ without succesful as long as I've tried to convert such chr in their relevant ascii octal code.

Thanks in advance!
Stefano